# watir-webdriver - load a Profile using headless gem

Tags: watir-webdriver, headless, headless-browser

The goal would be to set the profile the same way as in a regular Browser object,

```
$browser = Watir::Browser.new b, :profile => profile
```

Is it possible to load a firefox Profile using the
[headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem?

My current code,

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = "#{Dir.pwd}"
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf,application/x-tar-gz, application/x-gzip, application/x-compressed"

if $global_cfg['headless'] == 'on'
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start
    $browser = Watir::Browser.start url.to_s
else
    $browser = Watir::Browser.new b, :profile => profile
    $browser.goto url.to_s
end
```

Comment: Can you make question more clear? `headless` gem is an Xvfb wrapper, it has nothing to do with WebDriver's Firefox profiles.

Comment: The headless gem is required to virtualize the GUI execution on a remote Jenkins server with no x server installed. However, I also need to modify the Firefox profile so I can automate the download of a range of file types. I succeeded doing it using Watir::Browser.new b, :profile => profile
but what is the correct sintax to use that same profile using the headless mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same

```
if $global_cfg['headless'] == 'on'
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start
end

$browser = Watir::Browser.new b, :profile => profile
$browser.goto url.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks p0deje. Exactly the same way.. I erroneously thought headless Browser mode had to be started using Watir::Browser.start.